# GEDIT does not remember last cursor position inside text file after update to ubuntu 21.10

Tags: gedit, 21.10

I recently updated from ubuntu 21.04 to ubuntu 21.10. I have been using GEDIT as it helps saving the last cursor position after closing the file. After upgrade, every time I open a text file, the cursor sits at the top of the file.

My system specs are as follows.

```
Operating System: Ubuntu 21.10
KDE Plasma Version: 5.22.5
KDE Frameworks Version: 5.86.0
Qt Version: 5.15.2
Kernel Version: 5.13.0-19-generic (64-bit)
Graphics Platform: X11
Processors: 4 × Intel® Core™ i5-8250U CPU @ 1.60GHz
Memory: 7.6 GiB of RAM
Graphics Processor: Mesa Intel® UHD Graphics 620
```

Comment: https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/report-ubuntu-bug.html.en

Comment: Thanks. Filed a bug